# Display a clock face

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Display the 12 numbers on a clock face exactly like this:

```
           12            
     11           1      

 10                   2  


9                       3


  8                   4  

      7           5      
            6
```

To better see the grid, here's one with dots:

```
...........12............
.....11...........1......
.........................
.10...................2..
.........................
.........................
9.......................3
.........................
.........................
..8...................4..
.........................
......7...........5......
............6............
```

Note that the grid is stretched in width by a factor of two to make it look more square.

Also note that two-digit numbers are aligned with their ones digit in place. The 9 digit should be flush against the left.

Return or print the result as a multiline string (not a list of lines). Any trailing spaces are optional. The final newline also optional.

Comment: Are the spaces on the right (after 12, 1, 2, ...) or between rows necessary ?

Comment: @CreaZyp154 The trailing spaces are optional

Answer (score 26):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
Ｆ¹²«Ｍ⁻↔⁻¹⁴⊗÷×⁴ι³¦⁸⁻⁴↔⁻⁷÷×⁴﹪⁺³ι¹²¦³Ｐ←⮌Ｉ⊕ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7LCsJADEXX@hWzzMC4qBUUXRW7ESyI@AN9pBiYzsi8NuK3j4EqbgwEQpJzOf29db1tdc6jdQKKtRTP5aKxCaEhEz1Unf9MxUaJ2sZO4wAnE2pKNCDcaEIPfCKpRCm5lNhxzwzvfwFbJf5wjR2itnDR/FHOMWzxDZMHtok60MORCbA/4xiUuGJC5xGOrQ/s0juc0AT2ohl55ZxXSb8B) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Computes the offsets between each digit mathematically. Charcoal is 0-indexed (thus the `⊕` to output \$ 1 \ldots 12 \$), so the formulae for the horizontal and vertical offsets are as follows:

$$ \begin{align} \delta x &= \left \lvert 14 - 2 \left \lfloor \frac {4i} 3 \right \rfloor \right \rvert - 8 \\ \delta y &= 4 - \left \lvert 7 - \left \lfloor \frac {4i'} 3 \right \rfloor \right \rvert \end{align} $$

where \$ i' = i + 3 \pmod {12} \$.

Answer (score 23):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 91 bytes

Not a very clever approach, but I've failed to find anything shorter at the moment.

```javascript
_=>`K12
E11K1

A10S2


9W3


B8S4

F7K5
L6`.replace(/[A-Z]/g,c=>''.padEnd(Buffer(c)[0]&31))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dci7CoMwFADQ/X5ITaBGo30OERTskm4OhYpoyENaggmx7e@nLmc4b/ETqwwv/0kXp3Q0LI6smjgtoKWUU4Ca5l0BANdHudlcugPA7cyPcD9NJGhvhdQo6@v0OWTzXrIqSYgXql0Uar7G6IAk7vNhV1KMo3TL6qwm1s3IoC3@)

Comment: I love the use of Buffer() as alternative to `charCodeAt()`

Comment: @Downgoat Which makes me wonder if we should have a _Tips for golfing in Node.js_ question, for Node specific features. Not sure it's worth it, though.

Comment: Maybe add a separate answer that contains all the Node specific features, or at least a list linking all the different answers?

Answer (score 15):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>39</s> <s>33</s> 31 bytes

Thanks to *Magic Octopus Urn* for saving 6 bytes!

#### Code

```
6xsG12N-N•°£•NèØú«тR∞Nè¶×]\6».c
```

Some 33 byte alternatives:

```
711ćŸā•Σ°w•₂вú‚øJƵt3в¶×‚ø»6xŠ».c¦
6xsŸ5L•Σ°w•₂вúõ¸ì‚ζJï2ÝÂ«Ć¶×)ø».c
6xsG¶12N-N•Θ{©•₂вNèú«ƵB∞Nè¶×]6J.c
6xsG12N-N•Θ{©•₂вNèú«тR∞Nè¶×]6s».c
```

Uses the [**05AB1E** encoding](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/frKLY3dDIT9fvUcOiQxsOLQZSfodXHJ5xeNeh1Rebgh51zANyD207PD02xuzQbr3k//8B)

Comment: Nice answer! I like the use of `ÿ` with `.V`, very original! And funny how you've used `12¤` to get both `12` and `2` on the stack. I probably would have just used `12Y`, but I guess how is irrelevant, since both have 12 and 2 on the stack. If I would have tried this challenge in 05AB1E I would have ended way higher in byte-count.. Guess I still have much to learn. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Oh yeah, I forgot about `Y`. That would have been an easier option hahaha.

Comment: I don't know if I'm fixing the 6 in under 6 bytes: `6xsŸ5L•δ;Ì’•2ôúð.ø‚ζJ012∞S¶×‚ζJ.c` but you're welcome to anything of use in here.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Nice trick with the zip, I did not think of that.

Comment: @adnan props on `6xŠ»` too, I would've never thought of that.

Comment: NB: this can be changed to the rewrite by just replacing `∞` with `º`.

Answer (score 10):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), <strike>82</strike> <strike>76</strike> 73 bytes

```
00 C0 A2 0E BD 38 C0 29 03 A8 A9 0D 20 25 C0 BD 38 C0 4A 4A A8 A9 20 20 25 C0
BD 29 C0 20 D2 FF CA 10 E1 60 20 D2 FF 88 10 FA 60 36 35 37 34 38 33 39 32 30
31 31 31 31 32 31 31 2C 1A 4C 0B 5C 03 4C 00 06 2C 00 15 00 2C
```

- -6 bytes, thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170297/display-a-clock-face/170339?noredirect=1#comment411339_170319) for the clever idea :)
- another -3 bytes after Arnauld's idea not to treat leading `1` digits specially

The idea here is to only store the digits of all the numbers in the order they are needed. Additional info required is the number of newlines to prepend and the number of spaces in front.

The maximum number of newlines is `3`, so we need 2 bits for this, and the maximum number of spaces is `23`, therefore 5 bits are enough. Therefore, for each digit to print, we can squeeze this info in a single "control byte".

So, the data for this solution takes exactly 30 bytes: 15 single digits and 15 associated "control bytes".

#### [Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B%22controlPort2%22:%22joystick%22,%22primaryControlPort%22:2,%22keys%22:%7B%22SPACE%22:%22%22,%22RETURN%22:%22%22,%22F1%22:%22%22,%22F3%22:%22%22,%22F5%22:%22%22,%22F7%22:%22%22%7D,%22files%22:%7B%22clockface.prg%22:%22data:;base64,AMCiDr04wCkDqKkNICXAvTjASkqoqSAgJcC9KcAg0v/KEOFgINL/iBD6YDY1NzQ4MzkyMDExMTEyMTEsGkwLXANMAAYsABUALA==%22%7D,%22vice%22:%7B%22-autostart%22:%22clockface.prg%22%7D%7D)

Usage: `SYS49152` to start.

**Commented disassembly**:

```
         00 C0                          ; load address
.C:c000  A2 0E       LDX #$0E           ; table index, start from back (14)
.C:c002   .mainloop:
.C:c002  BD 38 C0    LDA .control,X     ; load control byte
.C:c005  29 03       AND #$03           ; lowest 3 bits are number of newlines
.C:c007  A8          TAY                ; to Y register for counting
.C:c008  A9 0D       LDA #$0D           ; load newline character
.C:c00a  20 25 C0    JSR .output        ; repeated output subroutine
.C:c00d  BD 38 C0    LDA .control,X     ; load control byte
.C:c010  4A          LSR A              ; and shift by two positions for ...
.C:c011  4A          LSR A              ; ... number of spaces
.C:c012  A8          TAY                ; to Y register for counting
.C:c013  A9 20       LDA #$20           ; load space character
.C:c015  20 25 C0    JSR .output        ; repeated output subroutine
.C:c018  BD 29 C0    LDA .digits,X      ; load current digit
.C:c01b  20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2          ; output
.C:c01e  CA          DEX                ; decrement table index
.C:c01f  10 E1       BPL .mainloop      ; still positive -> repeat
.C:c021  60          RTS                ; and done.
.C:c022   .outputloop:
.C:c022  20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2          ; output a character
.C:c025   .output:
.C:c025  88          DEY                ; decrement counting register
.C:c026  10 FA       BPL .outputloop    ; still positive -> branch to output
.C:c028  60          RTS                ; leave subroutine
.C:c029   .digits:
.C:c029  36 35 37 34 .BYTE "6574"
.C:c02d  38 33 39 32 .BYTE "8392"
.C:c031  30 31 31 31 .BYTE "0111"
.C:c035  31 32 31    .BYTE "121"
.C:c038   .control:
.C:c038  31 2C 1A 4C .BYTE $31,$2C,$1A,$4C
.C:c03c  0B 5C 03 4C .BYTE $0B,$5C,$03,$4C
.C:c040  00 06 2C 00 .BYTE $00,$06,$2C,$00
.C:c044  15 00 2C    .BYTE $15,$00,$2C
```

Comment: Could you save 2 bytes by using a subroutine doing `JSR $FFD2 / DEY / BNE loop / LDA .control,X / RTS` called for both newlines and spaces? I think it would be +10 bytes long and save -12 bytes in the main code.

Comment: Actually, I think you can save more bytes if the subroutine is doing `JSR $FFD2 / DEY / BPL loop / LDA .control,X / RTS` and the entry point is the `DEY`. This way, you don't have to test `0` in the main code.

Comment: Thanks nice idea, will edit later. The latter however won't work, I need a case that skips the whole loop.

Comment: If Y=0, `DEY / BPL / RTS` will exit immediately without processing any `JSR $FFD2`. (Note that with that scheme, the entry point of the subroutine must be `DEY`.)

Comment: @Arnauld Yep, that's clever :) Used this idea now, thanks!

Comment: I like the way you stored the extra `"1"` in the control byte. However, this is currently costing 9 bytes (`BPL / LDA / JSR` and the `AND $7F`). Encoding them as 3 extra 'standard' digits would cost only 6 bytes.

Comment: @Arnauld plus load `LDA digit2,X` and output `JSR $FFD2` which is 6 bytes as well? Or do you have a better idea here?

Comment: Ah now I get what you mean. Indeed, this should work :)

Comment: Maybe ... it still avoids two times explicit `0` checking (4 bytes) and one instance of `JSR`/`DEY`/`BNE` (6 bytes) at the expense of 2 times `JSR` (6 bytes) and one `RTS` (1 byte) ... should still be better, but I'll double-check :)

Comment: @Arnauld after quite some experimentation, I think it's shortest to keep the subroutine while using your suggestion of storing all digits :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>76 74</s> 70 bytes

```perl6
"K12
E11K1

A10S2


9W3


B8S4

F7K5
L6"~~say S:g{<:Lu>}=" "x$/.ord-64
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/1/J29CIy9XQ0NuQi8vR0CDYiIuLyzLcGEg6WQSbcHG5mXubcvmYKdXVFSdWKgRbpVfbWPmU2tXaKikoVajo6@UXpeiamfz/756fmGPFpYAAQGMhtCGyIBeXgqGBAiYAW6uAHYAco6BggUXGhAtqozmSoCmyKxTMAA)

Port of Arnauld's answer until I can come up with something shorter.

Answer (score 6):

## Java <s>8</s> 11, <s>141</s> 138 bytes

```java
v->{for(var x:"92BCN5BB92BNN1BA991CNNNJ995DNNN2I991ENN6H92FN93G".getBytes())System.out.print(x<59?" ".repeat(x-48):(char)(x>76?10:x-17));}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ZZDNbsIwEITvPMUqJ1siEUkbqEkLaugPrVRfkHqhHNxgaGhwIttJg1CePd2U3HrxeFfr2W98EJVwD9vvNsmEMfAmUnUeAKTKSr0TiQTelQBVnm4hIe@dVDTCXjPAw1hh0wQ4KLiDtnJn512uSSU01FOHBfGCh3GMyrkf3zPmLzjnr4yFD6jBCzYeOR8vWfDE2dWz4@2ljU9WGkLp6mSsPHp5ab1CIw6pb0M217KQwhIHnGHtXt/QKUm@hKaknk3Gc380rV1/QmnUtFFHV5SfGdL1kH8RjhiQrCw67tcbEPSSTnkJUWWW/Qt2mYR@bV8Zq4dIBOKYl8r2FlraUitQ8qd/RLprR7e@zG2ohzYZ/ilxPkbOEF36dU37Cw) (NOTE: `String.repeat(int)` is emulated as `repeat(String,int)` for the same byte-count, because Java 11 isn't on TIO yet.)

Explanation is similar as below, but it uses `" ".repeat(x-48)` for the spaces instead of format with `"%"+(x-48)+"s"`.

---

## Java 8, 141 bytes

```java
v->{for(var x:"92BCN5BB92BNN1BA991CNNNJ995DNNN2I991ENN6H92FN93G".getBytes())System.out.printf("%"+(x>58?"c":x-48+"s"),x>76?10:x>58?x-17:"");}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY9Na4NAEIbv@RXDQmGXVKm2Jlmlhpp@Q@cS6KX0sN2swdRocNfFEPztdk1zmZd5B4bn2QkrvN3md5Cl0Bo@RFGdJgBFZVSTC6kAxxXA1sUGJP0cw7LEdf3EDW2EKSQgVHAPg/XSU1431IoGupjwMFthlGUuEYPsgfNghYjvnEePLsM3Vzwhzl55@Iz89oX4W2Wyo1GaMrY@aqP2ft0a/9A4nJySKzKlXRotlkSSuPPuFlOiCbvu0vlsGdzE51PnBfOYEJb0QzICHtqf0gFeOM8We@dI18Y93X59g2D/gpUvadWW5cWtH/4A)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->{                        // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  for(var x:"92BCN5BB92BNN1BA991CNNNJ995DNNN2I991ENN6H92FN93G".getBytes())
                            //  Loop over the bytes of the above String:
    System.out.printf("%"+  //   Print with format:
     (x>58?                 //    If the character is a letter / not a digit:
       "c"                  //     Use "%c" as format
      :                     //    Else:
       x-48+"s"),           //     Use "%#s" as format, where '#' is the value of the digit
     x>76?                  //    If the byte is 'N':
      10                    //     Use 10 as value (newline)
     :x>58?                 //    Else-if the byte is not a digit:
      x-17                  //     Use 48-58 as value (the 0-9 numbers of the clock)
     :                      //    Else:
      "");}                 //     Use nothing, because the "%#s" already takes care of the spaces
```

**Further explanation `92BCN5BB92BNN1BA991CNNNJ995DNNN2I991ENN6H92FN93G`:**

- All the digits will be replaced with that amount of spaces. (For 11 spaces it's therefore `92`.)
- All 'N' are new-lines
- All ['A','J'] are clock digits ([0,9])

Answer (score 6):

## HTML + JavaScript (Canvas), 13 + 161 = 174 bytes

Arbitrary canvas positioning uses 6 bytes.

```js
with(C.getContext`2d`)with(Math)for(font='9px monospace',textAlign='end',f=x=>round(sin(x*PI/6)*6)*measureText(0).width*2,x=13;--x;)fillText(x,f(x)+80,f(9-x)+80)
```

```html
<canvas id=C>
```

With grid for comparison:

```js
with(C.getContext`2d`)with(Math){
    for(font='9px monospace',textAlign='end',f=x=>round(sin(x*PI/6)*6)*measureText(0).width*2,x=13;--x;)fillText(x,f(x)+80,f(9-x)+80)
    for(globalAlpha=0.2,y=-6;y<=6;y++)fillText('.'.repeat(25),6*measureText('.').width*2+80,y*measureText(0).width*2+80)
}
```

```html
<canvas id=C>
```

---

### Explanation of Positioning Formula

See my [JavaScript with SVG answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170350/47097).

Comment: I don't think this counts because since this is ASCII-art we are supposed to generate the exact byte-stream specifies in the challenge while this renders an image that looks like output.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>75</s> 68 bytes

```r
write("[<-"(rep("",312),utf8ToInt('*`®÷ĥĹĚä—M'),1:12),1,25)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVQynaRldJoyi1QENJScfY0EhTp7QkzSIk3zOvRENdK@HQusPbjyw9svPIrMNLDk33ledR19QxtAIpM9QxMtX8/x8A)

Compressed the digits positions.
Did this after spending lots of time trying to come up with a trigonometric answer (see history of edits).

Inspired by [this other R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170366/80010) buy J.Doe - upvote it !

Saved 7 bytes thanks to J.Doe.

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVQynaRldJoyi1QENJScfY0EhTp7QkzSIk3zOvRENdK@HQusPbjyw9svPIrMNLDk33ledR19QxtAIpM9QxMtX8/x8A "R – Try It Online") -  changed hash to avoid arithmetic and altered the `write` call to use the default separator.

Comment: @J.Doe It makes more sense this way. Of course not having documented my golf I have no clue why I did a convoluted hash in the first place...

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 97 bytes

```python
for i in range(7):w=abs(3-i);print'%*d'%(1-~w*w,12-i),'%*d'%(24-3**w-2*w,i)*(w<3),'\n'*min(i,5-i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw1zTqtw2MalYw1g3U9O6oCgzr0RdVStFXVXDULeuXKtcx9AIKKEDFTMy0TXW0irXNQJKZGpqaZTbGAPlYvLUtXIz8zQydUyBav//BwA)

Computes all spacings and newlines in the loop

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>88</s> 87 bytes

```
f=<<"k12{e11k1{{a10s2{{{9w3{{{b8s4{{f7k5{l6"
f c|c>'z'="\n"|c>'9'=' '<$['a'..c]|1<2=[c]
```

The encode-spaces-as-letters method (first seen in [@Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170298/34531)) in Haskell. Using `{` and expanding it to `\n` is one byte shorter than using `\n` directly.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc1NCsIwEEDhvacIQZiVxYm/hcQTuHPZdhGHpkpiCKYiOD27sW4e3@7dbPZ9CGUQRrTFGa2lR8U9okdmi@usmLl@b@Zej3nL7A5@x2EvF07QRCf4gJFtlH/WYECAXjZgoaqom1Ar01BXHvYe50F6jZfxeY5iKF9ywQ65rCilHw)

Answer (score 5):

## R, <s>168</s> <s>159</s> 125 bytes

The naive solution of writing the numbers at the prescribed points in a text matrix. Points are stored as UTF-8 letters decoded via `utf8ToInt`

```
"!"=utf8ToInt
write("[<-"(matrix(" ",25,13),cbind(!"LMFGSBCWAYCWGSM",!"AABBBDDDGGJJLLM")-64,-64+!"ABAAAA@BICHDGEF"),1,25,,"")
```

Dropped 9 bytes with JayCe's suggestion to use `write` and avoid defining the matrix.

Dropped another 34 bytes with JayCe's storage suggestion.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG! I think the dots are supposed to help visualize the pattern, but not part of the output.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! you can asve some bytes not defining `m` and using `write`: [TIO](https://tio.run/##LYyxDsJADEN/BWXKSUZqcrSlEn/CBIXhBhhOleDvrzmD7MFxnlxb@9SyPVWul6Po67bV8lU5CHyE5YT1Xt4PXdU8TkyYYQscGZ5hHWJiS1yt19SJmvtzoJ3O6YdF/GuIvMTQmfiIKQhuQyS1tgM). PS: you are not obliged to include a TIO link in your answer but it formats the answer nicely for you, see link icon on top of TIO page.

Comment: You can store the points in a string and overload the `!` operator to get to [125 chars](https://tio.run/##TU/BisJADL37Fdt4ydAIzrRWBYXttOuotCddRDxpd4U5OIUyYv@@Ox1FNi@BJO8lJE031Mvr3VRW1wZbVp0tamP39be9zrANk5ixwVBjhVwQjyihKfE5CYpIRMRJTJ6Z7/LoLe4pj9hj2gvG3oX3f0pXvTB2@dztm/mJCSWMdRDA8u5u2dcbYwePRttfhNNiBHg720a3CB/QX@E2UnXR5gcDKMqV2snskB6zg9qVQAGkqZQyz3OlttuiKIGNkphchI6SqbNPucnWufpaAXu@RQCs6/4A). Really nice solution!

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 32 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁶ẋ“¿×¿ Œ4ç4Œ!¿Ø‘ż“øn0œ’Œ?D¤Fs25Y
```

A full program which prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9qZWxsef//4oG24bqL4oCcwr/Dl8K/IMWSNMOnNMWSIcK/w5jigJjFvOKAnMO4bjDFk@KAmcWSP0TCpEZzMjVZ//8)**

#### How?

(I have not yet thought of/found anything shorter than `“¿×¿ Œ4ç4Œ!¿Ø‘` which seems long to me for this part - bouncing / base-decompression / increments, nothing seems to save!)

```
⁶ẋ“¿×¿ Œ4ç4Œ!¿Ø‘ż“øn0œ’Œ?D¤Fs25Y - Main Link: no arguments
⁶                                - space character
  “¿×¿ Œ4ç4Œ!¿Ø‘                 - code-page indices list = [11,17,11,32,19,52,23,52,19,33,11,18]
 ẋ                               - repeat (vectorises) -> [' '*11, ' '*17, ...]
                          ¤      - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                 “øn0œ’          -   base 250 number = 475699781
                       Œ?        -   first natural number permutation which would be at
                                 -   index 475699781 if all permutations of those same
                                 -   natural numbers were sorted lexicographically
                                 -   = [12,11,1,10,2,9,3,8,4,7,5,6]
                         D       -   to decimal lists = [[1,2],[1,1],[1],[1,0],[2],[9],[3],[8],[4],[7],[5],[6]]
                ż                - zip together = [[' '*11, [1,2]], [' '*17, [1,1]], ...]
                           F     - flatten = [' ',' ',...,1,2,' ',' ',...,1,1,...]
                            s25  - split into chunks of 25 (trailing chunk is shorter)
                               Y - join with new line characters
                                 - implicit print
```

Comment: LOL I'm actually surprised this is the naive approach.

Answer (score 5):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 96 bytes

```rust
||format!(r"{:13}
     11{:12}

 10{:20}


9{:24}


  8{:20}

{:7}{:12}
{:13}",12,1,2,3,4,7,5,6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvBDoIwEETv@xVLT22yB7agaA0fw8EmJFBNLael316LOKc3kzdx@6TiA67THLRBgeWZ0OOIZd/9K65TanRU4rjLgEeYa7EZALkVZ9tKcK/QH4B4@2/ihnyKv68itsRkqaOeBrrQ1ZQHvOMc0hIaraQa6LUxkMsX)

Answer (score 5):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>240</s> 235 bytes

```
++++++++++[>++>+>+++>+++++>++>++[<]>-]>>>++...........>-.+.<<.>.....>-..<...........>.<<..>.>.-.>-[<<.>>-]<++.<<...>>+++++++.>>+++[<<<.>>>-]<<------.<<...>..>+++++.<<<-[>>.<<-]>>>----.<<..>......>+++.<...........>--.<<.>............>+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7dCoAwCIUfSPQJ5LzI6KKCIIIugp5/HW3rxzlxnm/qdIzrvpzzVqs8ViACHsmbkV58gA4AU3sNamLuhv4y/6ohMcKUWgmOPVzyCwW0iXdGPYAgXNMaRr8xAloQXXOTB0Ebl8xvO32X6zWxWi8)

**Commented code**

```
++++++++++                              Put 10 in cell 0
[>++>+>+++>+++++>++>++[<]>-]            Loop 10 times incrementing to leave 0 20 10 30 50 20 20 in memory 
>>>++                                   30 plus 2 = 32 (ascii space)
...........>-.+.                        print 11spaces followed by 12 (ascii 49 50)
<<.>.....>-..<...........>.             print 1newline 5spaces 11 11spaces 1 
<<..>.>.-.>-[<<.>>-]<++.                print 2newlines 1space 10 19spaces 2
<<...>>+++++++.>>+++[<<<.>>>-]<<------. print 3newlines         9 23spaces 3
<<...>..>+++++.<<<-[>>.<<-]>>>----.     print 3newlines 2spaces 8 19spaces 4
<<..>......>+++.<...........>--.        print 2newlines 6spaces 7 11spaces 5
<<.>............>+.                     print 1newline  12spaces 6
```

A rare example where the text is repetitive enough that the brainfuck program is less than <s>twice</s> 1.6 times the length of the output!

2 bytes saved by suggestion from Jo King: `>>>>>>-` -> `[<]>-`

3 bytes saved by moving the third 20-place downcounter from far right of the ascii codes `10 30 50` to immediately to the left of them. Saves `<<>>` when filling the gap between `8` and `4` but adds 1 byte to the line `>>>++` .

**Original version**

```
++++++++++                              Put 10 in cell 0
[>+>+++>+++++>++>++>++<<<<<<-]          Loop 10 times incrementing to leave 0 10 30 50 20 20 20 in memory 
>>++                                    30 plus 2 = 32 (ascii space)
...........>-.+.                        print 11spaces followed by 12 (ascii 49 50)
<<.>.....>-..<...........>.             print 1newline 5spaces 11 11spaces 1 
<<..>.>.-.>-[<<.>>-]<++.                print 2newlines 1space 10 19spaces 2
<<...>>+++++++.>>+++[<<<.>>>-]<<------. print 3newlines         9 23spaces 3
<<...>..>+++++.>>>-[<<<<.>>>>-]<<<----. print 3newlines 2spaces 8 19spaces 4
<<..>......>+++.<...........>--.        print 2newlines 6spaces 7 11spaces 5
<<.>............>+.                     print 1newline  12spaces 6
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>145</strike> <strike>137</strike> 125 bytes

Only the tab positions are hard-coded: all the line spacings and clock values are generated in the loop.

Thanks again to ceilingcat for the suggestions.

```c
i,j,k;f(char*t){for(i=7;i--;t=memset(t+sprintf(t,"%*d%*d"+3*!j,"NHDA"[j]-65,6+i,"AMUY"[j]-65,6-i),10,k=j+i/4)+k)j=i>3?6-i:i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU47C8IwGNz9FTEiJE3ig/qgxioFBxfdHKQ4SNrql9oHTXQp/e21dRAO7gXHKfFQqh1Brl7vKEZbYyMoJs9dC1zzVCZEPe@VY2mdFBUBfy1BCGn9LM5MbIllpqwgtwmxHI@dqANmrjPUHJ@PhwCH@iZWS75iwHFwulz/gQDK5zOe@prBdEFZSrUPO3ffFRuQTdttouwOOfkUEFFUDxDqjyATet5Ndi4hhvZcvq35yab9Ag)

Comment: Suggest `"\r\7\3"[j]` instead of `"NHDA"[j]-65`

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](http://www.php.net/), 97 bytes

```php
<?=gzinflate(base64_decode(U1CAA0MjLghtqIAkyMWlYGiggAmMuLi4LBWwA2OgnIKCBRYZEy6IHQrmSIKmXMhKzAA));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42vSozLy0nsSRVIymxONXMJD4lNTk/JVUj1NDZ0dHAN8snPaOk0NMxu9I3PCfSPTM93THXt9Qn08THKbzc0cg/Pc/T29kpKDLKtdLM0yOwKDfY0zs3wjfDu8rRUVPT@v9/AA)

This is a hard coded compressed string. I couldn't find a solution shorter than this!

Comment: Can you put the binary compressed string in the source file and skip the base64_decode? I tried this and I get a 'gzinflate(): data error', but it might be possible if the source file was written witha hex editor instead of a text editor.

Comment: @bdsl actually I did that before and you don't need a HEX editor, you can just use PHP itself `file_put_contents($path, '<?=gzinflate("'.gzdeflate($clockString,9).'");');`, but I'm not sure how to post a code with binary data inside it. A file like that is 70 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>125</strike> <strike>109</strike> 105 bytes

```c
x,*d=L"<;1:2938475640P`P05";main(i){for(;i=d[12];printf("%*d",i/4,*d++-48))for(x=i&3;x--;)puts("");}
```

- -16 bytes (-3 for better loop arrangement, -13 for directly including the non-printable chars) thanks to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170297/display-a-clock-face#comment411318_170339).
- -4 bytes by replacing a division for a shift and abusing the fact that on many systems (like the one hosting TIO), `sizeof(wchar_t) == sizeof(int)` -- won't work on windows :) Thanks [ErikF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170297/display-a-clock-face#comment411343_170339) for the idea.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/79CRyvF1kfJxtrQysjS2MLE3NTMRNaAL4A9gT9AzsBUyTo3MTNPI1OzOi2/SMM60zYl2tAo1rqgKDOvJE1DSVUrRUknU98EaIi2tq6JhaYmSFmFbaaasXWFrq61ZkFpSbGGkpKmde3//wA)

This is a port of my general idea from [the 6502 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170319/71420) to C. It's a bit modified: Instead of having a flag for a leading `1`, the character is printed as a decimal by subtracting 48, so 10 - 12 are encoded as `:` to `<`.

Comment: [109 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/COjkjsUgrxVbJxtrQysjS2MLE3NTMRNaAL4A9gT9AzsBUyTo3MTNPI1OzOi2/SMM60zYl2tAo1rqgKDOvJE1DSVUrRUkn087OSEcrRVtb18RCUxOkrsI2U83YukJX11qzoLSkWENJSdO69v9/AA).

Comment: @JonathanFrech nice loop rearrangement, I wonder how I missed that one :o But really didn't expect gcc to accept non-printable characters in the source :)

Comment: As long as [the character can be represented in UTF-8,](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html) it's technically acceptable by the compiler. Whether that's a good thing rather depends on what you're doing :-)

Comment: Speaking of Unicode, you can save 3 more bytes by using wide characters: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/79CRyvF1kfJxtrQysjS2MLE3NTMRNaAL4A9gT9AzsBUyTo3MTNPI1OzOi2/SMM60zYl2tAo1rqgKDOvJE1DSVUrRUkn087OCGiKtrauiYWmJkhdhW2mmrF1ha6utWZBaUmxhpKSpnXt//8A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: Nice trick ... would break on windows because it assumes `wchar_t`==`int`, but will edit later ;)

Comment: That's why I like code golfing: I get to abuse UB and use all those "things you shouldn't do" that you pick up over time!

Comment: @ErikF used your idea now :) In fact, I've seen it in your submission and just forgot later.

Comment: One last thing I saw: replace `i>>2` with `i/4` to save another byte (and possibly move `main` to the footer for another 3): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/CWivF1kfJxtrQysjS2MLE3NTMRNaAL4A9gT9AzsBUyTpNI1OzOi2/SMM60zYl2tAo1rqgKDOvJE1DSVUrRUknU99ERytFW1vXxEJTE6SswjZTzdi6QlfXWrOgtKRYQ0lJ07r2P1CHQm5iZp6GpkK1QpqGprVC7X8A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ErikF thanks again, used the division! Although I guess it's allowed to submit a function that only works a single time, this "feels" somehow wrong :o

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, <s>94</s> <s>88</s> 82 bytes

Direct [Powershell format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html). `{i,w}` means a placeholder for a parameter with index `i`, width of the placeholder is `w` with right align.

```
"{11,13}
{10,7}{0,12}

 10{1,20}


9{2,24}


  8{3,20}

{6,7}{4,12}
{5,13}"-f1..12
```

## Powershell, 88 bytes

Port of [Arnauld's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) [Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170298/80745)

*-6 bytes thanks to @AdmBorkBork*

```
[RegEx]::Replace("K12
E11K1

A10S2


9W3


B8S4

F7K5
L6",'[A-Z]',{' '*("$args"[0]-64)})
```

To better see the grid, use `'.'` instead `' '`.

Comment: Why not string multiplication instead of `.PadLeft` for 88 bytes -- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PzooNd21ItbKKii1ICcxOVVDydvQiMvV0NDbkIvL0dAg2IiLi8sy3BhIOlkEm3BxuZl7m3L5mCnpqEc76kbFqutUqyuoa2koqSQWpRcrRRvE6pqZaNZq/v8PAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: That's a clever use of `-f`. Why don't you include links to [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYw7CoAwEAX7PUWwXsO@TfwdKGIRULSwWHL2aLQbhmGO/U7ntaWca@0MYIRCBuGpmDC0EDmIgVVepMWUNTZybrbwWxtbHb/ahnbo@hXeQ2t9AA "PowerShell – Try It Online") so others can see how your code works?

Comment: I have the error `This site can’t be reached` only. Sorry.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. It's a good resource. :-(

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 37 bytes

```
3B 32 35 75 07 0d 13 0c 22 14 35 18 44 74 5F 74 2B 46 6F 68 32 C4 52 7D 74 2A 31 32 25 31 32 7C 60 52 2D 29 73
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=3B+32+35+75+07+0d+13+0c+22+14+35+18+44+74+5F+74+2B+46+6F+68+32+C4+52+7D+74+2A+31+32+25+31+32+7C+60+52+2D+29+73&input=&warnings=0&hex=1) (raw bytes)

```
;25Dt_t+Foh2.DR}t*12%12|`R-)s
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%3B25Dt_t%2BFoh2.DR%7Dt%2a12%2512%7C%60R-%29s&input=%5B13%2C+19%2C+12%2C+34%2C+20%2C+53%2C+24%5D&warnings=1&hex=0) (Human readable)

```
                              - o = 0
;25                           - set line width to 25 characters
                              -      `[13, 19, 12, 34, 20, 53, 24]`
                              -       (In hex version, encoded in base 256, regular version in input field)
    t_t                       -     reversed(^[1:])[1:]
   D   +                      -    ^^ + ^
        Foh2.DR}t*12%12|`R-)  -   for i in ^:
         o                    -            o++
          h                   -           ^+1
           2.DR               -          divmod(^, 2)
               }t             -         (remainder*2)-1
                 *            -        quotient * ^
                  12%         -       ^ % 12
                     12|      -      ^ or 12 (12 if 0 else ^)
                        `     -     str(^)
                         R-   -    ^.rpad(i) (prepend spaces such that length i)
                            s -  sum(^)
                              - output ^ (with newlines added)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>315</s> 313 bytes

*saved 2 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!*

```
++++[>++++<-]>[>+++>+++>+++>+++>>++>+++>+++>+++<<<<<<<<<-]>+++++>++++>+++>++>++++++++++>>+++++++>+><<<...........>>.<<<<.>.>.....>>..<<...........>>.<<<..>.>>.>.<<<...................<<.>...>>++.<.......................<<<.>>...>..>-.<...................<<<<.>>>..>......>-.<...........<<<<<.>>>>.>............>-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5LCoAwDEQPFDonKHMRcaGCIIILwfPXJDVKpVMa8nkTMp/TdqzXspciqoEWcxrpWfPZ1jmksJm8GdPaqe3IKVQan0iYH9T31OgAMMCY1h3yBcaKoDevTPbtRjKhv8YZ4jnmz@UA4lq8WCk3)

all in one code block:

```
++++[>++++<-]>[>+++>+++>+++>+++>>++>+++>+++>+
++<<<<<<<<<-]>+++++>++++>+++>++>++++++++++>>+
++++++>+><<<...........>>.<<<<.>.>.....>>..<<
...........>>.<<<..>.>>.>.<<<................
...<<.>...>>++.<.......................<<<.>>
...>..>-.<...................<<<<.>>>..>.....
.>-.<...........<<<<<.>>>>.>............>-.
```

Comment: You can use `++++[>++++<-]>` for the 16 at the beginning.

Comment: @ovs Ah, of course, thanks!!

Comment: Lol, you have `><` in your code

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript with SVG, 188 bytes

Arbitrary line height of 120% uses 4 bytes.

```js
with(Math)for(s='<pre><svg viewBox=-8-8+16+16 style=font-size:1;text-anchor:end>',f=x=>round(sin(x*PI/6)*6),x=13;--x;)s+=`<text x=${f(x)*2}ch y=${f(9-x)*1.2}>${x}</text>`
document.write(s)
```

With grid for comparison:

```js
with(Math)for(s='<pre><svg viewBox=-8-8+16+16 style=font-size:1;text-anchor:end>',f=x=>round(sin(x*PI/6)*6),x=13;--x;)s+=`<text x=${f(x)*2}ch y=${f(9-x)*1.2}>${x}</text>`
for(y=-6;y<=6;y++)s+=`<text x=12ch y=${y*1.2} style=fill:#0002>${'.'.repeat(25)}</text>`
document.write(s)
```

---

### Explanation of Positioning Formula

Let `f(x) = round(sin(x * π/6) * 6)`.

Assuming the origin is the center of the clock, the grid coordinates of the right-most digit of any given clock number `x` is
[`f(x) * 2`, `f(9 - x)`].

Answer (score 2):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 69 bytes

```
{ReplaceF["l12
f11l1

b10t2


9x3


c8t4

g7l5
m6",/"\\l",sp&`*@STN]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@786KLUgJzE51S1aKcfQiCvN0DDHkIsrydCgxIiLi8uywhhIJluUmHBxpZvnmHLlminp6CvFxOQo6RQXqCVoOQSH@MXW/g8oyswrUbCpUUiLjv0PAA)

This encodes each run of spaces as: `NTS[count of spaces]`; `NTS` is the "numeric to short" builtin, which allows numbers to be expressed as strings. E.g., `NTS[95] = $R1` and `NTS[170297] = $XQO`. `STN` is the inverse of this builtin.

This answer replaces (`ReplaceF`) all occurences of letters (`/\l/`) in the input with the result of the function `` sp&`*@STN ``, which firsts decodes the letter and then repeats `sp` (a space) that many times.

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), <s>178</s> 165 bytes

<s>`var b="";for c in"L12nF11L1nnB10T2nnn9X3nnnC8T4nnG7L5nM6"{let i=c.unicodeScalars.first!.value;if c=="n"{b+="\n"}else if i>64{for _ in 0..<(i-65){b+=" "}}else{b+="(c)"}};print(b)`</s>

Based on what Downgoat posted, I've reduced this to 165 bytes:

`print("L12nF11L1nnB10T2nnn9X3nnnC8T4nnG7L5nM6".unicodeScalars.map{let x=Int($0.value);return x==110 ?"\n":(x>64 ?String(repeating:" ",count:x-65):"($0)")}.joined())`

Expanded out, with `$0` converted to a named variable:

`print("L12nF11L1nnB10T2nnn9X3nnnC8T4nnG7L5nM6".unicodeScalars.map { c in
    let x = Int(c.value)
    return x == 110 ? "\n" : (x>64 ? String(repeating:" ", count: x-65) : "(c)")
}.joined())`

The input string is encoded as follows: Uppercase letters (`A-Z`) represent blocks of spaces, offset by 65. So `A` means 0 spaces, `B` means 1 space, the first `L` means 11 spaces, etc. `n`s are converted to newlines. All other characters are printed as-is.

Run it online [here](https://tio.run/##DY1BC4IwGIb/yhgdNqjhTK0WJhQUgZ3y0MHL0BUL@5S5lRD99rXLy8NzeN7xo@828X4wGizBJY/hyHnJAfY8qmIA2NyWYQ/rKgE4rcoULhlmDnTTt@rayE6akb3k8O2URVN@DpVZxN6yc4pujbLOQNA55xEqcA1YkGmXJai42vD4IEYNStpAAiM8b3oHVkyLLKUC1yFEMf2xZ69BtYRS7/8) (thanks, mbomb007)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Many of us use Try It Online (TIO) for online interpreters to include a hyperlink to the program in our answers. Here is the one for your answer: https://tio.run/##JY1BC4IwGIb/yvpOSjScqRW2DgV1sVMeOgQx14SBfMacdhB/@1p2eeF5eV7e7qNrmzg3CEMqDpDXrSGSaISCxXhmrGAZ4pFFZYyIu/va52lbJoiXTZHiNYOxUdb7lkvao5btS92kaITpaK1NZxd0EE2vcl0TyTkgjNWSwwNhUk2niK/99pAl4@/46YFElO4DX66yNJxlAtMs/5eBDD3nb@OVoAqd@wI

Comment: Here's a golf of your answer that's 172 bytes. It uses a function instead: `{"L12NF11L1NNB10T2NNN9X3NNNC8T4NNG7L5NM6".unicodeScalars.map({(c)->String in let x=c.value;return x==78 ? "\n" : x>64 ?String(repeating:" ",count:x-65) : "\(c)"}).joined()}` (swift 3 (`-swift-version 3` on repl) because swift 4 dropped subtraction it looks like)

Comment: @Downgoat I reduced it another 3 bytes and made it compatible with Swift 4. See updated post.

Answer (score 2):

## vim, 103 bytes

```
25a <ESC>r30r9O0i <C-v><ESC>15l2xA <C-v><ESC><ESC>0"aDddqbYp<C-x>e<C-a>q2@a@b4@a@b6@aggqbYP<C-a>e<C-x>q@axr 2hr2@b4@a@b6@ayyjpr lr yyj2p2j2p2jp
```

`<ESC>` is 0x1b, `<C-a>` is 0x01, `<C-x>` is 0x18, and `<C-v>` is 0x16.

This includes all trailing spaces <strike>because I didn't notice they were optional until I'd finished</strike> for the additional challenge.

### Annotated

```
25a <ESC>r30r9                            # create the 9...3 line
o0i <C-v><ESC>15l2xA <C-v><ESC><ESC>"a0D  # create macro a that moves 2 spaces from the middle to the ends
                                          # 15 is a magic number that lets the same macro work for the 6 and 12 lines
dd                                        # delete empty line
qb                                        # record macro b to...
  Yp                                      #    duplicate line (down)
  <C-x>e<C-a>                             #    adjust numbers
q
2@a                                       # adjust spacing for line 8..4
@b4@a                                     # create line 7..5
@b6@a                                     # create line 6
gg                                        # move cursor to first line
qb                                        # record macro b to...
  YP                                      #    duplicate line (up)
  <C-a>e<C-x>                             #    adjust numbers
q
@axr 2hr2                                 # adjust spacing for 2-digit numbers
@b4@a                                     # 11..1
@b6@a                                     # 12
yyjpr lr yy                               # add a line of all spaces below 12, and copy to default register
j2p2j2p2jp                                # add the rest of the blank lines
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/38g0UUG6yNigyNLfIFNBTNrQNMeowhHIkDZQSnRJSSlMiiyQSGUsNHJIdEgyARFmDonp6UDhAMZUiUKHxIoiBaOMIiOEZGVlVkGRQk6RApBhVGAExgX//wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 151 bytes

```
foreach[a b c d][13 12 1""7 11 12 1 1""1""3 10 20 2 1""1"^/"0 9 24 3 1""1"^/"3 8 20 4 1""1""7 7 12 5 13 6 1""][print rejoin[pad/left b a pad/left d c]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3RCoMwDEV/5dIf0LRu3X5jr6WDronMMVSK/9@lToT7kHNIbopwfQiHWMelSMrvkPBCBsdADmRBxngQ7WMDjfoeVvPnZ2d63GEHuFM43NrGcFx4@FZwgXZem4thLdO8ochnmeawJu6@Mm76OuEERo6x1h8)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 132 bytes

```sql
PRINT SPACE(11)+'12
     11           1

 10'+SPACE(20)+'2


9'+SPACE(23)+'3


  8'+SPACE(19)+'4

      7           5
            6'
```

Only 12 bytes shorter than the trivial solution (`PRINT` of the entire string as-is).

Found a variation I like that is much longer (<s>235</s> 226 bytes), but much more SQL-like:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(SPACE(PARSENAME(value,4)),PARSENAME(value,3),
              SPACE(PARSENAME(value,2)),PARSENAME(value,1))
FROM STRING_SPLIT('11.1..2,5.11.11.1,. .. ,1.10.20.2,. .. ,. .. ,.9.23.3,
                   . .. ,. .. ,2.8.19.4,. .. ,6.7.11.5,12.6.. ',',')
```

`STRING_SPLIT` breaks it into rows at the commas, and `PARSENAME` splits each row at the dots. The 1st and 3rd are used for how many spaces to print, the 2nd and 4th are used for what to display.

(line breaks in this one are just for readability)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>112</s> <s>88</s> 87 bytes

A solution using string interpolation.

```python
print(f'''{12:13}
{11:7}{1:12}

 10{2:20}


9{3:24}


  8{4:20}

{7:7}{5:12}
{6:13}''')
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##JYwxDoAgEAR7XkGHdtyBovcgow0SQ2M2vP0U7SaTyZS77mcOquU6ch025xyIhUIzIJLUQELcjLHkwcL@RbMiCMdO1i6Iv0Xq9fTVmPvhfY2qDw)

*-25 bytes thanks to ovs and Herman L.*

Comment: And if you use [Hermans formatting string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170377/64121) you can get this to ~85 bytes.

Comment: One more byte with `{11:7}`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 123

`printf` does the heavy-lifting here:

```bash
n=" 0 a 0 a"
printf -vo %*s%*s\\n 0 a 13 12 7 11 12 1 $n 3 10 20 2$n$n 1 9 24 3$n$n 3 8 20 4$n 7 7 12 5 13 6
echo "${o//a}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzNCoQwDITvPsVQ6mVBNK3rz8E38VLFxb2kyypexGeviTBD5suQTGFbU@LBoEJQm@z3//L@QXFE5K9NNI78tORBDi2IdBIsQzYVnMiyEKGHq@Ef8Oi0qSW2euTw1g9NtsxrhLFnLMtwmZRu)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>135</strike> <strike>123</strike> 110 bytes

This uses a simple encoding where any `c` between `'a'` and `'z'` represents `c-'a'+1` repeated spaces, `` '`' `` represents a newline, and all other characters are left unchanged.

````c
f(i){char*s="k12`e11k1``a10s2```9w3```b8s4``f7k5`l6`";for(;i=*s;s++)i>96?printf("%*s",i-96,""):putchar(i%86);}
````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FczRDoIgFIDhe5@CsbkB6hZWJDHrVQ6xsDPKHNi6cD472c1/9e13zeBczp4hX9zDRpF6GmQLdymDBLByl1oA0N/91luXDgD@FI7wVECNf0dmsBfJpKrieNHqOkUcZ89oKRKtsdGqppSfp8/8nzMsO8XNmjdDXhZHxslSEOIZN8Wafw)

Comment: Suggest `*s=L"...";f(i){` instead of `f(i){char*s="...";`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 116 bytes

```perl6
my@a=["  "xx 13]xx 13;($_=pi/6*++$;@a[0+|6*(1.1-.cos);0+|6*(1.1+.sin)]=fmt ++$: "%2s")xx 12;@a>>.join>>.&{say S/.//}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z@30iHRNlpJQUGpokLB0DgWTFprqMTbFmTqm2lpa6tYOyRGG2jXmGlpGOoZ6uol5xdrWsP52nrFmXmasbZpuSUKQLVWCkqqRsVKmiBTjIAa7ez0svIz84CUWnVxYqVCsL6evn7t//8A)

(Ta @JoKing for saving 26 bytes)

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 142 bytes

```perl6
my@a=[[[32,32]xx 13]xx 13];for 1..12 {$_=$^b*pi/6;@a[round 6*(1-.cos);round 6*(1+.sin)]=[" $b".ords.tail(2)]}
{say S/^.//}(.[*;*].chrs) for @a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc1BC4IwGIDhe7/iQzxsq76xCV6GsP/QccyYWjQwJ1uBIv72RRB0eQ/P5Z1vcaxzfq7aNcaYSp4qaZcFRPWruocIAlFI2MprU7Ydmz2vlXYmhvc0QM2IOGMfElV/OGLyE7WNKaDsCgxxSPhyfiSS2v2wJbfChbfI@U7QMMUs9o@YKHxn2uX8AQ)

I wanted to do something... different. So this one calculates the positions of all the digits, via pairs of characters, strips off the initial space and prints the lines.

Easily modifiable for different parameters, e.g. a [45 character wide version with 17 digits](https://tio.run/##Tc1BC8IgGIDhe79Chge1@sJv1Q4y8H@IhduKhDWHFmyM/XYj6NDlPTyXd7zF/pzzc9auNsaUuCvRThM5nn5V9xCJBJAVWei1ppdGoBj9QVZKOxPDe@gIomByD21IXP3JFpIfuK1NQWhTQIhdgpfzPUNu180Cyc0rAyOUsNA@YuLk@9Iu5w8).

Comment: [116 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z@30iHRNlpJQUGpokLB0DgWTFprqMTbFmTqm2lpa6tYOyRGG2jXmGlpGOoZ6uol5xdrWsP52nrFmXmasbZpuSUKQLVWCkqqRsVKmiBTjIAa7ez0svIz84CUWnVxYqVCsL6evn7t//8A "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing: Ta, I've pasted that in & made it a wiki.

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 290 bytes

```
{iii}ii{c}c{ii}dddcic{dddd}c{ii}iiccccc{ii}dddcc{dd}iii{c}c{ii}dddc{dddd}icc{ii}iic{ii}dddcdc{d}dddddd{c}ccccccccc{ii}ddc{dddd}ccc{iiiii}dddc{dd}ddddd{cc}ccc{ii}dc{dddd}dccc{ii}iicc{ii}iiiic{dd}dddd{c}ccccccccc{ii}c{dddd}ddcc{ii}iicccccc{ii}iiic{dd}ddd{c}c{ii}ic{dddd}dddc{ii}ii{c}cc{ii}iic
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9LDsQwCENP1EON7KnqdZcRZ09Dg9PpsOHjZxD8frjrPLbem6SQGgKjDJIQ2kicAwkZ1lIasxc/acG856lkMSJxx5R94@71bIriEUaLJNaBytIy/O@3h/h9wj7b/IQWzkLufeXs/QI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 49 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
12∙11∙1７«１╋¶10∙2‾⁶２╋¶¶9∙3‾⁹３╋¶¶8∙4‾⁵３╋¶7∙5‾¹２╋6）ｒ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=MTIldTIyMTkxMSV1MjIxOTEldUZGMTclQUIldUZGMTEldTI1NEIlQjYxMCV1MjIxOTIldTIwM0UldTIwNzYldUZGMTIldTI1NEIlQjYlQjY5JXUyMjE5MyV1MjAzRSV1MjA3OSV1RkYxMyV1MjU0QiVCNiVCNjgldTIyMTk0JXUyMDNFJXUyMDc1JXVGRjEzJXUyNTRCJUI2NyV1MjIxOTUldTIwM0UlQjkldUZGMTIldTI1NEI2JXVGRjA5JXVGRjUy,v=8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Cm`, 32 bytes

```
6d6(12n-»§⟩»niǎnS꘍J₁SṘmni⌊¶*)_6W
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJDbSIsIiIsIjZkNigxMm4twrvCp+KfqcK7bmnHjm5T6piNSuKCgVPhuZhtbmnijIrCtiopXzZXIiwiIiwiIl0=)

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 52 bytes

```
00000000: e000 9200 2c5d 0010 6c02 2323 71ec 327c  ....,]..l.##q.2|
00000010: cf28 700c 02f9 d7eb 5929 59a9 e1c8 62ab  .(p.....Y)Y...b.
00000020: 6d60 3fad 8aea 9fc7 e472 69f0 37f4 133e  m`?......ri.7..>
00000030: ff8e e100                                ....
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc@xCgIxDAbg3af4wUVBQppqe3XQ53AQbHupCCeo4Oa7n1Fv9x/@JeQLKc9SBj0/r@PIU7ZQaySxkrrpwewYobJAvHhEpxVeYgXIsjoSDTSf30les5/gzKhNOkTmCpaW0Ect2CRJVjlBXe0QJBczFrcPQ4flwbrQZIgZoQ8M33KPLmtGajVC11EQUrNBbGs47xW4nvZfgx4XikS7yfBmtNapnbNf/uSzPo5v)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 73 bytes

Port of Arnauld's answer.

```perl
say"K12
E11K1

A10S2


9W3


B8S4

F7K5
L6"=~s,[A-Z]," "x(ord($&)-64),erg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBmqmdoYP2/OLFSydvQiMvV0NDbkIvL0dAg2IiLi8sy3BhIOlkEm3BxuZl7m3L5mCnZ1hXrRDvqRsXqKCkoVWjkF6VoqKhp6pqZaOqkFqX//w8A)

As a one-liner:

```perl
perl -E'say"K12\nE11K1\n\nA10S2\n\n\n9W3\n\n\nB8S4\n\nF7K5\nL6"=~s,[A-Z]," "x(ord($&)-64),erg'
```

Another approach, but longer:

```perl
map$s.=$_%26?{12,12,32,11,44,1,80,10,100,2,157,9,181,3,237,8,257,4,293,7,
305,5,325,6}->{$_}||" ":"\n",1..338;
say$s
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <s>99</s>, 91

<s>`print"%13d\n%7d%12d\n\n%3d%20d\n\n\n9%24d\n\n\n%3d%20d\n\n%7d%12d\n%13d"%(12,11,1,10,2,3,8,4,7,5,6)`</s>

```
print"""%13d
%7d%12d

%3d%20d


9%24d


%3d%20d

%7d%12d
%13d"""%(12,11,1,10,2,3,8,4,7,5,6)
```

Thanks to Jo King

<s>Spaces hardcoded in -- I'm sure its possible to golf the `\n`s down, by repeating but I don't know how...</s>

Comment: You can use a multi-line string. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69ESUlJ1dAkhUvVPEXV0CiFi0vVOEXVyADI4LJUNTIB0XARmBqQBpA@DUMjHUNDHSA00DHSMdax0DHRMdcx1THT/P8fAA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 93 bytes

```js
console.log((

_=>`F 12
A11F 1

 10FE2


9FCB3


  8FE4

B7F 5
AC6`.replace(/[A-F]/g,c=>''.padEnd('0x'+c-5))

)())
```

Port of [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170298/) to general JS

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>47</s> 42 bytes

```
•1)âÝÈÝ‰ʒ%и&ñjÓU‰÷JêĆ+•₆B'X¶:AuðAuÇ31&×‡.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMiQ83Diw7PPdxxeO6jhg2nJqle2KF2eGPW4cmhQO7h7V6HVx1p0wYqe9TU5qQecWiblWPp4Q1A3G5sqHZ4@qOGhXrJ//8DAA)

```
•...•₆B'X¶:AuðAuÇ31&×‡.c  # trimmed program
•...•                     # push 1902039976984631753317213270923121051329258518010...
      B                   # in base...
     ₆                    # 36...
          :               # with all...
       'X                 # literal...
          :               # s replaced by...
         ¶                # newline...
          :               # s...
                     ‡    # with each...
           Au             # letter...
                     ‡    # replaced by the corresponding...
              Au          # letter...
                Ç         # 's codepoint...
                   &      # bitwise and...
                 31       # literal...
             ð            # " "...
                    ×     # s...
                      .c  # with each line centered more to the left
                          # implicit output
```